# Is it possible to get the value of a <td> element using onclick?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I currently have a table that has a list of email template names being echoed using php.  Below is part of the php code.  I'm trying to grab the table value and pass it to my JS file where a future AJAX command will pass it to a different file (that I won't have any issues with).  My first attempt to alert out the value stated that the value was undefined.  My second attempt showed the type of element it was inside (at the time it was a span).  Now it's not showing anything.  Suggestions?

PHP code:

```
<table class="departments">
<tr>
<th scope="col" style="width: 175px;">Email Name</th>
';
$get_depts = mysql_query("SELECT dept_name FROM depts where bus_id = '{$_SESSION['bus_id']}'");
while(($department = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_depts)))
{
    echo '
    <th scope="col" style="width: 175px;">'.$department['dept_name'].'</th>
    ';
}
echo '
</tr>
';
$get_emails = mysql_query("SELECT id, email_name from emails where bus_id = '{$_SESSION['bus_id']}' ORDER BY email_name ASC");
while(($email = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_emails)))
{
    echo '
    <tr>
    <td id="test" onclick="moveValue()">'.$email['email_name'].'</td>
    ';
```

Current JS code:

```
function moveValue()
{
var x = document.getElementById(test);
var y = x.innerHTML;
alert(y);
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to start learning jQuery http://jquery.com/

Comment: You did not open tag <? PHP?> Anywhere ..

Comment: @MateiMihai jQuery isn't required for this.

Comment: “Is it possible to get the value of a `<td>` element using `onclick`?” Yes. Yes, it is.

Comment: I specifically stated i was only showing part of my php code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript:

```
var y = document.getElementById("test").innerText;
```

jQuery:

```
$("#test").text();
```

To get the HTML:

```
var html = document.getElementById("test" ).innerHTML;
```

jQuery:

```
$("#test").html();
```

Comment: I tried using your suggestion and when I click one of the <td>'s it's sending back "undefined".  Thoughts?

Comment: @CBC_NS: `.innerText` won't work in Firefox. Try `.innerHTML`.

Comment: the jquery worked well.  I was able to get the first element.  I think part of the issue is that the <td> element is being looped.  No matter which "cell" I click, it is alerting the same value.  Is there a way to get the specific one?

Comment: It'll alert the same value because you're getting the text/HTML for the `<td>` tag with id `test`.

Comment: Best to use el.[textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) as it has better support.

Comment: @vascowhite Could it be possible to make this work if I set the <td> id equal to a php variable.  Say something like <td id="'.$somevar.'">.

Since everything is looping as a result of the query, the php variable would increment.  Thus each ID would be unique.  Is this doable?

Comment: @CBC_NS Yes, that is exactly the way to do it, but take a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18125942/212940), it doesn't require any id's.

Answer (score 2):

You id attribute would be the same for every td inside the loop. So JS would not know which element you want.

You could try passing `this` into the `onclick` method

HTML

```
<td onclick="moveValue(this);">
```

JS

```
function moveValue( elem )
{
    alert(elem.innerHtml);
}
```

I would take a look at `jQuery` if I were you. It makes all this stuff much easier to achieve.

Comment: As easy as drinking a glass of water

Answer (score 1):

With javascript:

To get raw text without any elements or:

```
somevar=document.getElementById ( "test" ).innerText;
```

To get full html code of  tag. Contents will be stored in 'somevar' variable.

```
somevar=document.getElementById ( "test" ).innerHTML;
```

Comment: I tried using this before, and I am getting "undefined".  Thoughts?

Comment: @CBC_NS the way you are generating your td's means you will have several with the same id's. Id's must be unique otherwise behaviour is undefined. You need to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to get into all the problems with your code as there are rather a lot. However, getting the value of a `<td>` element by clicking is trivial to achieve.

You first need to assign a click handler to each cell in your table. The easiest way to do this is to loop through each cell and assign the handler like so:-

```js
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i = 0; i <= cells.length; i++){
    cells[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}

function clickHandler()
{
    alert(this.textContent);
}
```

Then every time you click on a cell the `clickHandler()` will be called and you can run whatever code you wish.

You can see it working in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dFdTA/)

Lots of information here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either by

```
function moveValue()
{
  var x = document.getElementById('test');
  var y = x.innerHTML;
  alert(y);
}
```

or by:

```
function moveValue(element) {
  var y = element.innerHTML;
  alert(y);
}
//with the following html code:
<td onclick="moveValue(this)">'.$email['email_name'].'</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

its work.

```js
function clickValue(elem) {
  var x = document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML;
  alert(x);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th>Coba</th>
  <tr>
    <td id="1" onclick="clickValue('1')">value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="2" onclick="clickValue('2')">value yg ke 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Change `id="*anyvalue*"` and `clickValue('*anyvalue*')`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.