# Button to add selected row to another table

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have fixed my previous issue of adding data from 1 table to another. Now I have a problem that when the button at the end of the row is clicked, it inserts the last row of that table instead of the selected row. How can I fix my code so it inserts the row which the button is pressed into the new table instead of the last row?

eg table of what it does now

```
AA11AAA BMW 320I [ADD]
BB11BBB BMW 325I [ADD]
CC11CCC BMW 330I [ADD]
```

if I was to click on the button on the first row (AA11AAA BMW 320I) it will add the last row to the new table

```
CC11CCC BMW 330I
```

I want it to add the row that the button is clicked so if the first row button is clicked it adds the first row to the new table

```
AA11AAA BMW 320I
```

I hope this is clear, here is my code.

```
<tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="regNo" value="<?php echo $row['regNo'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="carMake" value="<?php echo $row['carMake'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="carModel" value="<?php echo $row['carModel'] ?>">
    <td><?php echo $row["regNo"] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["carMake"] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["carModel"] ?></td>
    <td><button onclick="addRowToTable()">ADD</button></td>
</tr>
```

**Script**

```
function addRowToTable() {
var table = document.getElementById("newCarTable");
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
cell1.innerHTML = "<?php echo $row["regNo"] ?>";
cell2.innerHTML = "<?php echo $row["carMake"] ?>";
cell3.innerHTML = "<?php echo $row["carModel"] ?>";
}
```

php script

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT regNo, carMake, carModel
        FROM vehicles";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);  
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
      {
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
 {
?>
```

How one of my tr looks like in page source

```
<tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="regNo" value="AA11AAA">
    <input type="hidden" name="carMake" value="BMW">
    <input type="hidden" name="carModel" value="320I">
    <td>AA11AAA</td>
    <td>BMW</td>
    <td>320I</td>
    <td><button onclick="addRowToTable(AA11AAA,BMW,320I)">ADD</button></td>
</tr>
```

I am now trying to add the new table records to my database

```
        <table id="newCarTable">
        <form action = "addNewCarTable.php" method = "post">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </table>
```

addNewCarTable.php

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$curRegNo = $_POST['regNo'];
$curCarMake = $_POST['carMake'];
$curCarModel = $_POST['carModel'];

$_SESSION["regNo"] = $curRegNo;
$_SESSION["carMake"] = $curCarMake;
$_SESSION["carModel"] = $curCarModel;

$sql = "INSERT INTO newCars(regNo, carMake, carModel)
        VALUES('$curRegNo', '$curCarMake', '$curCarModel')";
```

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode (usig PHP variables) the value of the innerHTML. Get those values from the item that was clicked.

Comment: would this be something to do with the ID of the row?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125204/is-it-possible-to-get-the-value-of-a-td-element-using-onclick

Comment: In this example I want to add one drop down box in a new table column is is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's a bad practice to mix Javascript and PHP like that. (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126671/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-have-php-in-your-javascript)

Your problem is that you are using PHP in javascript wrong. PHP renders your DOM (Including javascript), then javascript gets executed. Therefore, the numbers in the function will be static, not dymanic. **Your final script will be rendered like this:**

```
function addRowToTable() {
    var table = document.getElementById("newCarTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell1.innerHTML = "CC11CCC ";
    cell2.innerHTML = "BMW ";
    cell3.innerHTML = "330I ";
}
```

By the time your script gets executed, the numbers are already hardcoded. You can varify this by looking at the sourcecode of the site in your browser.

**What you have to do is get the numbers out of the DOM, instead of using PHP.**
I don't know your PHP script but something like this could possibly work:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT regNo, carMake, carModel
        FROM vehicles";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);  
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
      {
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
 {
   $curRegNo = $row["regNo"];
   $curCarMake = $row["carMake"];
   $curCarModel = $row["carModel"];
?>
```

Your table row:

```
<tr>
  <input type="hidden" name="regNo" value="<?php echo $row['regNo'] ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="carMake" value="<?php echo $row['carMake'] ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="carModel" value="<?php echo $row['carModel'] ?>">
  <td>
    <?php echo $row["regNo"] ?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $row["carMake"] ?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $row["carModel"] ?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button onclick="addRowToTable('<?php echo $curRegNo ?>','<?php echo $curCarMake ?>','<?php echo $curCarModel ?>')">ADD</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And then adding parameters to your Javascript function:

```
function addRowToTable(regNo, carMake, carModel) {
    var table = document.getElementById("newCarTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell1.innerHTML = regNo;
    cell2.innerHTML = carMake;
    cell3.innerHTML = carModel;
}
```

Here's a working CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgeaOx
It's using hardcoded numbers, because I can't render the template using PHP but it'll show how the Javascript is working in general.

Comment: I think that is what I said already, you only use more words. You do not supply any information on how to go from here.

Comment: First of all I did. Secondly my answer is way more specific than your one-line comment, also adding additional information why it is a bad practice. Thirdly, don't downvote correct answers just because you are butthurt. Any additional information helps to understand the issue.

Comment: I posted my comment 10 seconds before you edited your answer. So, now you do, but then you didn't. It is a good answer now, not the best but it will work. Removed the downvote. I am not too fond of answers that include capitals. There is hardly ever a need to shout.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried using your code but when I click the buttons nohing happens, I have added my php script (sorry I should have included this earlier) to the op

Comment: My bad! I forgot to add '' to the onclick parameters. Therefore it was interpreted as a variable, not a string and couldn't be found. I'll edit my answer and include a codepen, where you can see a working example!

Comment: I have added the page source of 1 of the tr's in op

Comment: Yes, the parameters weren't recognized as strings because of the missing quotation marks. I updated my answer, it's untested but should work now. Note that I also added to the PHP.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! I really appreciate you helping me out!

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann Hi again, is it possible to add these values in the new table to my sql database? I have managed to get it connected to the database however the records do not get added.